# Find a continuous function that is always less than or equal to its own integral

Tags: calculus, functions

I am having difficulty coming up with examples of functions $f$ defines on $[0,1]$ such that $$f(t) \leq \int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds$$.

I see that the is required to be that $f(0)=0$, and that the derivative of $f$ should be less than $f(t)$,

but past this I have only been able to think about the solution $f(x)=0$.

Hints are greatly appreciated

Comment: For $f(t)=e^{ct}$, you don’t have $f(0)=0$, so that’s out. Think of some *very* simple function $f(t)$ for which $f(0)=0$, calculate $\int_{0}^{t} f(s) ds$, and if the inequality isn’t true, see if you can adjust something to make it true.

Comment: I can obtain some with the log function.

Comment: To avoid some trivial examples, I'm guessing $f$ should be continuous?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Take, for example:

$$f(t) = 1 - e^{2t}.$$

Then $\int_0^t f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s = t + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}e^{2t}$. We have

$$\int_0^t f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s - f(t) = t + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}e^{2t} - (1 - e^{2t}) = t + \frac{1}{2}(e^{2t} - 1) \ge 0.$$

Comment: There is no function if you insist that $f(0, \infty) \subseteq (0, \infty)$; let me know if you'd like some hints about that.